# git rebase: merge notes into commit message

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-notes

Given a commit with notes attached, can I take the message in the note and merge it into the commit's message when I do a rebase?

The background of this question is that I have a large repository imported via git-tfs that has a huge amount of notes linked to individual commits and while I am cleaning up the repository I would like to resolve the notes and merge them into the corresponding commit's messages.

Comment: This would be a very nice and useful feature to have. Notes are handled very differently by different rewrite and move-stuff-around commands (like cherry-pick) and putting the notes in the commit message is really the safest way to preserve them. So you might wanna (1) merge notes into the commit message while doing a rewrite and then (2) put them back as notes after the rewrite.

Answer (score 2):

Not currently, no.  There's no fundamental reason it could not be done, but the support for notes-on-commits is still kind of primitive.  Rebase can now *copy* a note when it *copies* a commit, but it does not offer the ability to squash notes when using squash.

If you want to implement this yourself, you should start with how `git notes` actually work, which I'll describe here rather briefly.  Git stores an auxiliary commit under the ref name `refs/notes/commits`.  This commit contains a series of files with weird-looking names, such as:

```
5d/01/301f2b865aa8dba1654d3f447ce9d21db0b5
```

for example.  If you take the slashes out of the file name, the result is a hash ID.  The *contents* of this file are the note for commit `5d01301f2b865aa8dba1654d3f447ce9d21db0b5`.

To update notes, or add new notes, Git will:

- extract the notes commit to a temporary area;
- create or update the file corresponding to the desired commit;
- use the resulting set of files to make a new commit, whose parent is the current `refs/notes/commits` commit; and
- update `refs/notes/commits` to store the hash ID of the new commit.

In effect, this is a lot like checking out the `refs/notes/commits` commit as a branch, except that you can't do that since `refs/notes/commits` is not a *branch* name.  (Also, Git uses a bunch of shortcuts here to avoid populating a full working tree.)

Hence, to merge the notes of commits C1 and C2 that have been squashed into new commit C3, you would:

- memorize the three hash IDs;
- check out or otherwise inspect the desired notes commit—this might be the *previous* one at this point, depending on where you do all this work—to find out how many layers of `xx/xx/xx/xx` to use (this varies: the notes code adds another layer whenever the tree gets "too crowded" at any given level; the actual level is implicit in the file names, but if you never split or join the names you don't have to worry about this);
- locate the files corresponding to C1 and C2, and combine them with whatever algorithm you like (probably union-merge);
- read the notes for C3 if needed (if you were working on C3's parent above) into a temporary index, or make sure you have C3's notes in this temporary index in any case;
- compute the number of layers to use for a C3 note, and create or update the appropriate file in the temporary index; and
- use the temporary index to make a new commit whose parent is the `refs/notes/commit` commit, then update `refs/notes/commit` to store the new commit's hash ID.

You've now updated the notes for commit C3, so that when `git log` goes to show commit C3, if it's also showing notes, it will read the for-C3 file in your new commit.

Comment: Thank you for this extensive explanation. Do you think it could be possible to automate these steps during a `git filter-repo` run to identify each commit that has a note attached and then fold that node into the respective commit?

Comment: @lanoxx: Given that filter-repo is written in Python and you therefore have the source code, it's just a [Small Matter Of Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_matter_of_programming). Seriously, how hard that would be to do, I have no idea. It doesn't sound *trivial* but Python would give you nice data structures (dictionaries and lists).